# How to get location in android

Tags: android, location

Please tell me what is wrong in this code as I am not getting location using this code.Plese let me know if this the correct ways or is their any better way to get the location perodically or for every 5 min

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_CODE);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 300000, 0, this);
            location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                Log.e("getLatitude", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                Log.e("getLongitude", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                return location;
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(this, "LOCATION NOT FOUND1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
           }
        }
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_CODE);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 300000, 0, this);
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
       if (location != null) {
            Log.e("getLatitudeNET", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            Log.e("getLongitudeNET", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
            return location;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "LOCATION NOT FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return null;
       }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "CONNECTION LOST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is your output? Are the permissions set?

Comment: i m getting null if i take the result of this line in location object
 locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

Comment: yes permission are set  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: So you get a toast saying "LOCATION NOT FOUND", right?

Comment: yes i get this toast for both gps and network

Comment: Where are you even assigning location a value?

Comment: i have assinged the value like this  location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK‌​_PROVIDER);    still getting null